# Power automate - can i get power automate to 'see' what "View" is active when trigger runs?

Tags: filter, sharepoint, power-automate

i hope i can make this make sense.

I need to try and get power automate to fill in file properties dependant on what view is selected at the time. I have 2 level filtering using columns.

Column A = Bananas
Column B = Ripe

View saved as "Ripe Bananas" so when selected the view only shows the files that are tagged as Ripe and Bananas.

What i want is for when someone has this view open and the add a file for it to be automatically logged as Ripe + Bananas.

Maybe its not possible - but i can work out the 'update file' element and can use a condition for IF X then add Y but what i can work out is how to get power automate to read what view is currently selected.

Maybe I'm asking too much? Trying to safe guard the filing structure from the rest of the work force....

Comment: PowerAutomate desktop? Yea? If so, your tags need changing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot get the name of selected SharePoint document library view from where the new file is created/uploaded, if you are using Power Automate cloud flows (automated flows) and triggers like "When a file is created" OR "When a file is created or modified", etc.

This is a by design or limitation of Power automate automated flow triggers.

If you want Microsoft to provide view name/information with automated flow triggers, you can add new idea at: [Power Automate Ideas forum](https://ideas.powerautomate.com/d365community/forum/086dd68e-597f-ec11-8d21-0022482e8f9f)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ganesh, but I see some alternative approaches though:

- you say 'rest of the work force' so you might base your condition on identity or group membership
- you could use power apps to create distinct input platforms for select user groups which use default values for these fields. You can then control who can access the apps.
- you could enable management of Content Types and create a 'Ripe Bananas' content type. This would make 'Ripe Bananas' an option at the 'New Item' button for the list. Content types are also handy because you can manage required/optional/hidden columns on content type level.